# How to get video duration fro AVAsset in Swift

Tags: swift, avasset, avurlasset

It might be duplicate question but I spent to much time for solution. I download a mp4 file to documentary directory. I can get all file names with this function:

```
func listFilesFromDocumentsFolder() -> [String]? {
    let fileMngr = FileManager.default;
    let docs = fileMngr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].path
    return try? fileMngr.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docs)
}
```

And I want to get all of these file's time length. Let me show what I try:

```
var downs = listFilesFromDocumentsFolder()!
for i in 0...downs.count - 1 {
    if downs[i] == ".DS_Store" {
                continue
    }
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    if let documentDirectory= urls.first as! NSURL as! NSURL { 
         let yourFinalVideoURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(downs[i])
         let asset = AVURLAsset(url: yourFinalVideoURL!) as AVURLAsset
         let totalSeconds = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration))
         let minutes = totalSeconds / 60
         let seconds = totalSeconds % 60
         let mediaTime = String(format:"%02i:%02i",minutes, seconds)
         print(yourFinalVideoURL)
         print(mediaTime)
}
```

the output is

```
Optional(file:///Users/utf8/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D4F341F1-38A2-498B-99F0-076BE9164A5C/data/Containers/Data/Application/718927F7-4E39-43A8-B760-2A468F82A10F/Documents/viki50102klr.mp4)
00:00
```

In my opinion I did wrong when I try to get url of my video file. But how to fix that. I try a lot of things. Even I check if the file is exist or not. Which its exist ofcourse.

Also I try

```
AVAsset(url: URL(url: yourFinalVideoURL)!)
```

unfortunetely it does not work..

Comment: What do you get if you print `totalSeconds` instead of `mediaTime`?

Comment: Unrelated but why all the really bad casting with `NSURL`?

Comment: Hi Maddy, its 0(zero) also...

Comment: My friend I spent too much time this thing and I try too much thing. but got nothing. Its bad casting but I try other things too. the result is fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't cast your url to NSURL. Just get your documents directory url, and append your filename and extension to it. Besides that you can get `CMTime` seconds property which is a double and use `String(format:)` method to properly display the time in `"h m s"` format:

```
let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let videoURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(downs[i])    
let duration = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL).duration.seconds
    print(duration)
let time: String
if duration > 3600 {
    time = String(format:"%dh %dm %ds",
        Int(duration/3600),
        Int((duration/60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)),
        Int(duration.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)))
} else {
    time = String(format:"%dm %ds",
        Int((duration/60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)),
        Int(duration.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)))
}
print(time)
```

Comment: Yup thats it. thank you. Also thank you for correcting bad nsurl casting